# turn colunm into raw in r

Tags: r, rows

[image]

Hello guys, I have a data frame with the columns "Auto", "ClasPri" and "Total". For each "Auto" I can have 4 different "ClasPri" and a "Total" for each "ClasPri". I wanted to make each "Auto" appear only once and the other columns to be "0, 1, 2, 3" with their respective "Total". Can someone help me?
The first image is as it is and the second as it should be.

[image: The first image is how it is and the second is how I wanted it to look]

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Try `xtabs(Total~Auto+ClasPri)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just trying to pivot your data on `ClasPri`. Here's a dplyr / tidyr way to do that:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

arrange(df, ClasPri) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = ClasPri, values_from = Total, values_fill = 0) %>%
  arrange(Auto)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>    Auto   `0`      `1`     `2`     `3`
#>   <int> <int>    <int>   <int>   <int>
#> 1   343     0   688160 8260000       0
#> 2   453  6000 29168829 7663334 2275200
#> 3   469     0  7888857       0  540000
#> 4   609     0        0       0       0
```

---

**Data used**

```r
df <- data.frame(Auto    = c(343L, 343L, 453L, 453L, 453L, 453L, 469L, 469L, 609L), 
                 ClasPri = c(1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), 
                 Total   = c(688160L, 8260000L, 6000L, 29168829L, 
                             7663334L, 2275200L, 7888857L, 540000L, 0L))

df
#>   Auto ClasPri    Total
#> 1  343       1   688160
#> 2  343       2  8260000
#> 3  453       0     6000
#> 4  453       1 29168829
#> 5  453       2  7663334
#> 6  453       3  2275200
#> 7  469       1  7888857
#> 8  469       3   540000
#> 9  609       1        0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>